# Ubuntu/OpenVPN - how to access private network when connection to public interface:

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenVPN.

This is my server network interfaces:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 00:0c:29:1f:8c:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet xx.xx.76.149/27 brd xx.xx.76.159 scope global ens160
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1f:8c15/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 00:0c:29:1f:8c:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 10.32.53.175/27 brd 10.32.53.191 scope global ens192
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1f:8c1f/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
  link/none
  inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::310e:bddc:f467:681b/64 scope link stable-privacy
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have installed an openvpn client and when I connect I want to be able to access interface `ens192` and all machines in that network. aka all machines in `10.32.53.160/27`.

As far as I know I need to route the traffic from `tun0` to `ens192`. Bare in mind the public interface is this one `ens160`.

Is this one even possible and how ?

Answer (score 0):

This is from an [openvpn setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-9-firewall-configuration).(Step 9)

Adding these lines to the beginning of `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0 (change to the interface you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

And setting default forward policy to accept in `/etc/default/ufw`:

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

Should allow you to redirect the traffic to that interface.

---

I'm not sure if this is required, but an additional setting that I use is redirecting the gateway in the server config:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Adding this in the server config effects all the clients.

This setting could be done client specific with adding this line not in the server config file, instead in the client-config files. In server config, add this line:

```
client-config-dir ccd
```

Then create a folder in server's folder called `ccd` and create a file within that folder with the common name of the client (suppose it's Venelin) `/etc/openvpn/server/servername/ccd/Venelin`:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```